# AJAX request based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have below code that gets data from an api and puts it in a table. What Im trying to achieve is a function where the ajax request takes an input value and takes only data from the api that matches the input value. Any suggestions how I should do?

```
function stats() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/",
        data: {
            second_name: document.getElementById("search-word").value,
        },

        success: function(response) {
            var statistik = response.elements;
            var body = document.querySelector("#search-table tbody");
            var x = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < statistik.length; i++) {
                var newRow = body.insertRow(-1);
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    var x = newRow.insertCell(j);
                }
            }
            var rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
                rows[i + 1].cells[0].append(statistik[i].second_name);
                rows[i + 1].cells[1].append(statistik[i].selected_by_percent);
                rows[i + 1].cells[2].append(statistik[i].goals_scored);
                rows[i + 1].cells[3].append(statistik[i].assists);
                rows[i + 1].cells[4].append(statistik[i].total_points);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="search-table" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="rank">Name</th>
                <th id="rank">Selected by %</th>
                <th id="rank">Goals</th>
                <th id="rank">Assists</th>
                <th id="test">Total Points</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Input element:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
    <input type="text" id="search-word" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Salah...">
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't that the job of the API in question?

Comment: The API request works but it takes the complete dataset from the url. This is whats not working: second_name: document.getElementById("search-word").value. The input value that I want to send to the API to get data only based on that.

Comment: There is no input element in the provided HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button to triger the API call

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
    <input type="text" id="search-word" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Salah...">
    <button id="search-button">search</button>
</div>
```

Update your function

```
function stats(value, successListener) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/",
        data: {
            second_name: value,
        },

        success: successListener
   })
}
```

Add an event listener in jQuery

```
$('#search-button').click(function() { 
   var value = $('#search-word').val()

   if (value && value.length > 0) stats(value, function(response) {
        var statistik = response.elements;
        var body = document.querySelector("#search-table tbody");
        var x = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < statistik.length; i++) {
            var newRow = body.insertRow(-1);
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                var x = newRow.insertCell(j);
            }
        }
        var rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            rows[i + 1].cells[0].append(statistik[i].second_name);
            rows[i + 1].cells[1].append(statistik[i].selected_by_percent);
            rows[i + 1].cells[2].append(statistik[i].goals_scored);
            rows[i + 1].cells[3].append(statistik[i].assists);
            rows[i + 1].cells[4].append(statistik[i].total_points);
        }
    })
});
```